# Wordpress website - www version is throwing an error message

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wwwroot

This is only with the "www" version The issue is that when I type in the browser www.hawkwoodpartners.com, it's throwing an error message -> "There has been a critical error on your website."
Which is not so detailed what is going on, so:
 - Hosting GoDaddy Wordpress Ultimate.
 - www version is set as a cname record to the root domain.
 - Tried to set wp_debug - true, bug nothing is displayed.
 - Tried a bunch of redirect rules to set in the .htaccess from the www to non-www version, but nothing happens. I think it's not getting to the htaccess file to redirect but the error is the first thing to hit. For example:

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hawkwoodpartners.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hawkwoodpartners.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Tried to disabled htaccess - nothing.

I would appreciate any suggestions on what this might be or how can I redirect www to the root domain.

(Just to clarify, I don't know if the www version was working before though, always accessing a website via domain.com and not www.domain.com)

Comment: Some Plugins or theme issued your site getting injected with some code so you can try disabling your one by one plugin or theme and check

Answer (score 0):

Ahh the issue was within the database where home & site URL was